# remove all data from sphinx database

Tags: php, sphinx

i want to know how to delete all data from sphinx table.

because i would like to store new data to the table.

thanks and advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, there is no such thing as a sphinx table, there are only index files.

If you want to delete all the sphinx indexes that you currently have stop sphinx and delete all the index files in your sphinx's data folder; then you can run indexer again, which will create new index files.

Comment: hey i have another question.
i am getting document id only from result of sphinx.
i need to get all the columns from the table.
what will i change in conf file or any place.
if u know please let me to inform.

Comment: You need to get 2 things right (probably you already did the first one).

1. Set the sql_query property (if you are using sql) in the sphinx config file to something like: "SELECT id, field1, field2 FROM myTable", so that sphinx will know where to get the documents

2. Make your fields sphinx attributes, so that sphinx knows what to store in it's indexes. For example if 'field1' is an integer, you should have a line in your sphinx config file like this: "sql_attr_uint = field1".

See the sphinx documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

We were getting our CPU maxed out via sphinx indexer.  And sphinx took over our disk "No space left on device"... by making a 70GB file 4X larger than our database.  We found our problem was we were running the indexer in a cron, every 10 minutes... sometimes the indexer would take more than 10 minutes... the jobs would stack up.  Solution:

```
ps aux |grep indexer
kill ___;#job number of indexer processes
ls -alS /var/lib/sphinx/data|head
rm /var/lib/sphinx/data/*.tmp.*
#adjust cron to run less frequently...
#add disk space...
```

So in this case instead of deleting all of the sphinx index... I only deleted the tmp files that had stacked up, and recovered tons of space that way.